# Errors when calling functions from File class?

Tags: unity, unityscript, file

When I try something like `File.Delete("Assets/a.txt");` it gives me a error saying

> Unknown identifier: 'File'.

In Unity Documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Windows.File.html 
it gives an note saying "this class is only available when targeting Universal Windows Platform." What does this mean?

In top of unity documentation it says `File` is a class in `UnityEngine.Windows`

So I tried `Windows.File.delete("Assets/a.txt")`.

Now the error changed to

> Language feature not implemented: UnityEngine.Windows.

What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: As stated in the doc _This is an alternative for System.IO.File class. Note: this class is only available when targeting Universal Windows Platform._. It is an alternative to `System.IO.File` and only works for MS Windows and Windows Phone. Why not just use `System.IO.File`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states, the function you are trying to call is "only available when targeting the Universal Windows Platform," or UWP. You're not targeting that platform currently, and the function is unavailable to you.

UWP isn't "standard" Windows, it's a cross-device common application platform introduced with Windows 10. It's typically synonymous with "stuff that goes into the Windows app store."

So there's a good chance you don't *want* to be targeting UWP, since you don't need to, and should thus use a different API to delete a file such as the normal `System.IO.File` APIs.

If you really do need to target UWP, you'll have to modify your project appropriately to target the platform. Unity has some [guides and tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/taking-unity-games-universal-windows-platform) on the subject.